# How to set validation for style="display: none;" element using `Jquery Form validator`?

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-validator

How to set validation for `style="display: none;"` element using `Jquery Form validator` [sample](http://www.formvalidator.net/).

I have `form` with tabs in which tab which `style="display: none;"` applied to not activated tab. my `form` is being submitted even if other tab element validation is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Elements with display none cold not be validated, to solve this problem you can add style visibility: hidden on your HTML element.

Eg: `<input type='text' style="visibility: hidden">`